# CVPixelBufferCreate does not care Planar format

Tags: ios, replaykit

I try to rotate CoreVideo '420f' image without transfer to RGBA.
The incoming CMSampleBuffer Y-plane bytesPerRow is width + 32.

That means Y-plane row size is 8bit * width + sizeof(CVPlanarComponentInfo).

But if I call CVPixelBufferCreate(,,,'420f',,) , BytesPerRow == width.
CVPixelBufferCreate() does not care about planar format and did not add 32bytes.

I tried

```
vImage_Buffer myYBuffer = {buf, height, width, bytePerRow};
```

But there is no parameter for bitsPerPixel. I cannot use for UVBuffer.

I tried

```
vImageBuffer_Init(buf, height, width, bitPerPixel, flag);
```

But there is no parameter for bytesPerRow.

I like to know how to create vImageBuffer or CVPixelBuffer with '420f' planar format.

This is under construction code for rotation

```
NS_INLINE void dumpData(NSString* tag, unsigned char* p, size_t w) {
    NSMutableString* str = [tag mutableCopy];
    for(int i=0;i<w+100;++i) {
        [str appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x ", *(p + i)]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
- (CVPixelBufferRef) RotateBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer withConstant:(uint8_t)rotationConstant
{
    vImage_Error err = kvImageNoError;
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    size_t outHeight = width;
    size_t outWidth = height;

    assert(CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer) == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange);
    assert(CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(imageBuffer) == 2);
    NSLog(@"YBuffer %ld %ld %ld",   CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0), CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0),
        CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0)); // BytesPerRow = width + 32
    dumpData(@"Base=", CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer), width);
    dumpData(@"Plane0=", CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0), width);

    CVPixelBufferRef rotatedBuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn ret = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, outWidth, outHeight, kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange, NULL, &rotatedBuffer);
    NSLog(@"CVPixelBufferCreate err=%d", ret);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(rotatedBuffer, 0);
    NSLog(@"CVPixelBufferCreate init %ld %ld %ld p=%p",   CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 0), CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 0),
        CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 0), CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 0));
        // BytesPerRow = width ??? should be width + 32

    // rotate Y plane
    vImage_Buffer originalYBuffer = { CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0), CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0),
        CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0), CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0) };
    vImage_Buffer rotatedYBuffer = { CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 0), CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 0),
        CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 0), CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 0) };
    err = vImageRotate90_Planar8(&originalYBuffer, &rotatedYBuffer, 1, 0.0, kvImageNoFlags);
    NSLog(@"rotatedYBuffer rotated %ld %ld %ld p=%p", rotatedYBuffer.width, rotatedYBuffer.height, rotatedYBuffer.rowBytes, rotatedYBuffer.data);
    NSLog(@"RotateY err=%ld", err);
    dumpData(@"Rotated Plane0=", rotatedYBuffer.data, outWidth);

    // rotate UV plane
    vImage_Buffer originalUVBuffer = { CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1), CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1),
        CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1), CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1) };
    vImage_Buffer rotatedUVBuffer = { CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 1), CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 1),
    CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 1), CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(rotatedBuffer, 1) };
    err = vImageRotate90_Planar16U(&originalUVBuffer, &rotatedUVBuffer, 1, 0.0, kvImageNoFlags);
    NSLog(@"RotateUV err=%ld", err);
    dumpData(@"Rotated Plane1=", rotatedUVBuffer.data, outWidth);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(rotatedBuffer, 0);

    return rotatedBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found vImageBuffer BytesPerRow extra 32 byte is optional. Some Apple API add 32 byte on each row, some API does not add.

Actually questioned code works fine. CVPixelBufferCreate() creates buffer without extra 32 byte. vImageRotate90_Planar8() supports both formats, with 32 byte and without 32 byte.